# Messaging middleware that uses HTTP as a transport

Tags: c++, c, http, embedded, message-queue

I'm looking for options that would allow a client to receive messages (push notifications) from a server. The client is an ARM/Linux embedded device similar in capabilities to a Raspberry Pi.

Because the client could be behind a firewall, I'd like to use message-oriented middleware (MOM) that can transport on top of HTTP. I think that rules out MOMs that are based on AMQP.

The MOM server should support the Linux platform. The MOM should also provide a C or C++ client library that can be compiled on an ARM/Linux platform.

I am aware of the HTTP long polling technique, as well as HTML 5 WebSockets and Server-Sent Events. But I'd prefer a higher-level (yet lightweight) solution that takes care of transporting messages between point A and point B over HTTP. It doesn't matter much if the messages have to be formatted as XML, JSON, plain text, or binary.

Comment: I apologize if "message-oriented middleware" is no longer the buzzword of the month for these types of technologies.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder what's the point of firewalls if everything ends up being tunnelled through HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

Two that I have used successfully are [XML-RPC](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/default.html) and [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html).

- XML-RPC:

  > It's a spec and a set of implementations that allow software running on disparate operating systems, running in different environments to make procedure calls over the Internet.
  >
  > It's remote procedure calling using HTTP as the transport and XML as the encoding. XML-RPC is designed to be as simple as possible, while allowing complex data structures to be transmitted, processed and returned.
- gSOAP:

  > The gSOAP toolkit is a C and C++ software development toolkit for SOAP/XML Web services and generic (non-SOAP) C/C++ XML data bindings. The toolkit analyzes WSDLs and XML schemas (separately or as a combined set) and maps the XML schema types and the SOAP messaging protocols to easy-to-use and efficient C and C++ code. It also supports exposing (legacy) C and C++ applications as SOAP/XML Web services by auto-generating XML serialization code and WSDL specifications. Or you can simply use it to automatically convert XML to/from C and C++ data. The toolkit supports options to generate pure ANSI C or C++ with or without STL.

Comment: Using these RPC-based technologies, is it possible for the client to receive notification of events from the server?

Comment: It would be more RSS like, so the client would poll at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, these are the available MOM technologies that use HTTP as a transport, and which feature a C/C++ client library:

### [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/)

> Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) is a communications
>   protocol for message-oriented middleware based on XML (Extensible
>   Markup Language).The protocol was originally named Jabber, and
>   was developed by the Jabber open-source community in 1999 for near
>   real-time, instant messaging (IM), presence information, and contact
>   list maintenance. Designed to be extensible, the protocol has also
>   been used for publish-subscribe systems, signalling for VoIP, video,
>   file transfer, gaming, Internet of Things applications such as the
>   smart grid, and social networking services. ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP))

### [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)

> Apache ActiveMQ is an open source message broker written in Java
>   together with a full Java Message Service (JMS) client. It provides
>   "Enterprise Features" which in this case means fostering the
>   communication from more than one client or server. Supported clients
>   include the obvious Java via JMS 1.1 as well as several other "cross
>   language" clients. The communication is managed with features such as
>   computer clustering and ability to use any database as a JMS
>   persistence provider besides virtual memory, cache, and journal
>   persistency. ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_ActiveMQ))

### [Zerogw](https://github.com/tailhook/zerogw)

> Zerogw is a http to zeromq gateway. Which means it listens HTTP,
>   parses request and sends it using zeromq socket (ZMQ_REQ). Then waits
>   for the reply and responds with data received from zeromq socket.
>
> Starting with v0.3 zerogw also supports WebSockets. Websockets are
>   implemented by forwarding incoming messages using ZMQ_PUB socket, and
>   listening clommands from ZMQ_SUB socket. Each WebSocket client can be
>   subscribed to unlimited number of topics. Each zeromq message it
>   either control message (e.g. subscription) or message to a specified
>   topic which will be efficiently sent to every WebSocket subscribed to
>   that particular topic. ([from the GitHub zerogw page](https://github.com/tailhook/zerogw))

---

There's also the HyperText InterORB Protocol (HTIOP), but TAO seems to be the only CORBA ORB that supports it. There doesn't seem to be anyone using it (please correct me if I'm wrong).

There is [work in progress](http://portals.omg.org/dds/content/specifications-progress#Web_Enabled_DDS) to make OMG's [Data Distribution Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_distribution_service) (DDS) web-enabled.

I'm also warming up to the idea of using WebSockets for bidirectional communications, despite their "low level" nature. For those interested, available C/C++ libraries include:

- [libwebsockets](http://libwebsockets.org)
- [websocket++](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp)
- [QWebSockets](http://kurtpattyn.github.io/QWebSockets/)
- [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) (C++ web development toolkit which includes support for WebSockets)

There is an open [Websocket Application Messaging Protocol](http://wamp.ws/) (WAMP) that provides asynchronous messaging patterns for remote procedure calls and the publish-subscribe pattern. There are a number of [implementations](http://wamp.ws/implementations/) for WAMP, but none of them are written in C/C++.

Comment: Please let me know if I'm missing any technologies that fit the criteria I've specified in my question.